# need help reading a file into a binary tree

Tags: c++

`enter code here`ok for a class project i need to make a spell checker. but first i need to read the txt file into the binary tree and I just can not figure it out can anyone help me

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <fstream>

#include "Binarytree.h"

#include "Spellchecking.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string sentence;
    Binarytree bintree("");
    cout << "Please enter a sentence" << endl;
    cin >> sentence;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile("words_nonalpha.txt", ios::binary);
    /*if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }   */

    myfile.open("words_nonalpha.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

ok, so I am about to put in my binary tree.h I thought that if I would add an ifstream and the name of the file it would work but it does not. sorry if my code is just terrible i just started this spring

```
#ifndef BINARY_TREE_H
#define BINARY_TREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Binarytree {
public:
    string value;
    Binarytree* left;
    Binarytree* right;
    ifstream myfile("words_nonalpha.txt");

    Binarytree(string value);

    void Add(string value);
    void Addall(vector<string>);
    void OutputAll();
    bool Find(string value, Binarytree*& returningNode);
    vector<bool> FindAll(vector<string>, vector<Binarytree*>&);
    void remove(string, bool);
    vector<string> TreetoVector();

    Binarytree* FindGreatest(Binarytree*);

private:
    void Add(Binarytree*& node, string value);
    void OutputAll(Binarytree* node);
    Binarytree* Find(Binarytree* node, string value);
    void remove(Binarytree*, string);
    Binarytree*& ParentTrap(Binarytree*, string);
    void TreetoVector(Binarytree*, vector<string>&);
    int Compare(string, string);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Remove `ifstream myfile("words_nonalpha.txt");` from inside your `class Binarytree {}`

Comment: You probably want to read a line at a time using the `Add(string value);` function to add the words to the tree. Your commented out while loop in main() looks reasonable. Provided each line or `"words_nonalpha.txt"` contains exactly 1 word.

Comment: `ifstream myfile("words_nonalpha.txt", ios::binary);` you don't want `ios::binary`. This should be a text file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Apply The Single-responsibility Principle

Classes should follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which states that

> ...  Every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. *(Taken from wikipedia)*

This means that your `Binarytree` class has one purpose and one purpose only: to act as a binary tree. This means that the `Binarytree` class shouldn't store a file or a stream object. If creating a binary tree from a file is a common operation, you can provide it as one of the constructors for `Binarytree`, but the `Binarytree` object shouldn't *own* the file.

#### Creating a binary tree from an input stream

Using the definition of a binary tree you gave in your original question, this is pretty simple! This is what the constructor would look like:

```
BinaryTree::Binarytree(std::istream& source) {
    std::string word;
    while(source >> word) // This returns true if a word was read successfully
    {
        this->Add(word); 
    }
}
```

This constructor will accept an `std::ifstream`, or you could read directly from `std::cin`.